# Putnam: Understanding a proof that a cancellative semigroup $S$ s.t. for any $s\in S$ the set of powers of $s$ is finite, is a group.

Tags: finite-groups, contest-math, proof-explanation, semigroups, binary-operations

> $B2.$  Let $S$ be a non-empty set with a binary operation (written like multiplication) such that:
>
> (1) it is associative;
>
> (2) $ab = ac$ implies $b = c$;
>
> (3) $ba = ca$ implies $b = c$;
>
> (4) for each element, the set of its powers is finite.
>
> Is $S$ necessarily a group?

I understand the solution given:

Answer: yes.

Let a be any element. We show that for some n > 1 we have an = a. The set of its powers is finite, so for some r > s we have ar = as. If s = 1, we are done. If not, put b = as-1, then b ar-s+1 = b a, so we may cancel to get an = a with n = r - s + 1 > 1. Now put e = an-1. Then we have ea = ae = a.

Now take any b. We have a(eb) = (ae)b = ab, and cancelling gives eb = b. Similarly, (be)a = b(ea) = ba, so be = b. Hence e is an identity.

Also a has an inverse. If n - 1 = 1, then a = e, so a is its own inverse. If n - 1 > 1, then an-2 is its inverse.

Now if b is any other element, we may use the same argument to find another identity f and an element c such that cb = bc = f. But we have e = ef = f, so the identity is unique and c is an inverse for b.

> The problem I am having is that they don't mention anything about the closure of such set $S$ under the operation.

For example, take $S = \{1,2,3\}$ under multiplication. I wouldn't say this is a group because $2\times3$ is not in $S$ but it fills all the criteria of the problem. What am I misunderstanding about closure? Is it something so obvious they don't even need to mention it in the solution? Thanks.

Comment: The most "compact" definition of a group I've ever seen is a non-empty set $G$ with an associative operation $\times:G^2\to  G $ such that for any $a,b\in G$ there is a unique $c\in G$ and a unique $d\in G$ such that $a\times c=b=d\times a.$

Comment: A "binary operation" by definition is closed.  Multiplication is not a binary operation on {1,2,3} *because* it is not closed.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet [This](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/projects/gtsax/) might interest you. Also, a semigroup S is a group if and only if for every $a\in S$ we have $aS=S=Sa$.

Answer (score 4):

A "binary operation on a set $S$" is a map $S \times S \to S$. Multiplication on $S = \{1,2,3\}$ is a map $S \times S \to \{1,2,3,4,6,9\}$ not $\to S$.

It doesn't make sense to ask whether or not a binary operation is closed. "Closure" comes up when dealing with subalgebras (sub-algebraic structures). That is, we have a binary operation $\mu : S \times S \to S$ and I have some subset $T \subset S$. Then $\mu$ restricts to a map $T \times T \to S$ and the question of closure is whether or not we can restrict the codomain to $T$ as well.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thanks.